# Only Return Rows Where Row Count >= 2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

Table has duplicate data in it.  I am in need of identifying the data that is duplicated in a structure like such - identifying each storeID that is duplicated by Hambasa

```
ABC BLUE 2
ABC Green 2
ABC Orange 2
BET Blue 2
BET Green 2
BET Orange 2
```

This is sample DDL and the query using Row_Number() I attempted.  What would be the proper way to get the result I am after?  I am actually wanting to delete the duplicates, so that each storeID only has 1 entry for each Hambasa.

```
    Declare @TMI Table (HAMBASA varchar(10), storeid varchar(10))
Insert Into @TMI (storeid, hambasa) VALUES
('ABC', 'Blue'), ('ABC', 'Green'), ('ABC', 'Orange'),
('ABC', 'Blue'), ('ABC', 'Green'), ('ABC','Orange'),
('NYC', 'Blue'), ('NYC', 'Green'), ('NYC', 'Orange'),
('BET', 'Blue'), ('BET', 'Green'), ('BET', 'Orange'),
('BET', 'Blue'), ('BET', 'Green'), ('BET', 'Orange')


;With pan As
(
    Select HAMBASA, storeid
    ,RN = Row_Number() Over (Partition By storeid Order By HAMBASA ASC)
    FROM @TMI
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where's the primary key?

```
DELETE records FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HAMBASA, storeid ORDER BY HAMBASA) AS HambasaCount
    FROM @TMI) records
WHERE records.HambasaCount > 1
```

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=d477a5344ee1ae466f4c5b589115eed7

Answer (score -2):

You can write code such as following:

```
SELECT *
FROM TestTable
WHERE ID NOT IN
(
SELECT MAX(ID)
FROM TestTable
GROUP BY NameCol)
GO
```

Refer: https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/12/19/sql-server-select-and-delete-duplicate-records-sql-in-sixty-seconds-036-video/

Comment: This answer assumes that there is an `ID` column. The question shows otherwise.